# stuff in stuff when joining extra table?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

See table `TABLE` below:

```
ID    FIELD_1
-------------
1     123
1     456
1     789
2     111
```

I wanted to list all `FIELD_1`s per ID, as follows:

```
select [ID],
       stuff((
           select '; ' + [FIELD_1]
           from   [TABLE] t1
           where  t1.[ID] = t2.[ID]
           for    xml path ('')
       ),1,1, '') as [FIELDS]
from   [TABLE] t2
```

Output:

```
ID    FIELDS
------------
1     123; 456; 789
2     111
```

**But now;** each `FIELD_1` can have multiple entries in another table (`TABLE2`):

```
FIELD_1    FIELD_2
------------------
123        A
123        B
456        B
111        C
111        X
111        Z
```

I need to add these to my output, as follows:

```
ID    FIELDS
------------
1     123 (A, B); 456 (B); 789
2     111 (C, X, Z)
```

So I tried this by joining as follows:

```
select [ID],
       stuff((
           select '; ' + [FIELD_1] + [FIELD_2]
           from   [TABLE] t1
           where  t1.[ID] = t2.[ID]
           for    xml path ('')
       ),1,1, '') as [FIELDS]
from   [TABLE] t2
left join [TABLE2] t3 on t2.[ID] = t3.[ID]
```

But this is returning a row for each occurance of `FIELD_1` in `TABLE2`.

What is the correct way for this query? Do I need to use `STUFF()` in the existing `STUFF()` select?

Comment: Join the tables first, *then* try to aggregate the strings, ie `FROM t1 inner join t2 on t1.Field_1=t2.Field_1` etc.. `STUFF` doesn't aggregate strings, it's used to eliminate the leftofers of converting the values into XML.

Comment: This doesn't help me. I believe that I am doing exactly that.. joining first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
declare @t2 table (id int)
    insert into @t2 values (1),(2)

declare @t1 table (id int, field_1 varchar(55))
    insert into @t1 values (1,'123'), (1,'456'),(1,'789'),(2,'111')

declare @t3 table (field_1 varchar(55), field_2 varchar(55))
    insert into @t3 values ('123','A'), ('123','B'),('456','B'),('111','C'),('111','X'),('111','Y')

select  [ID],
        stuff(( select '; ' + [FIELD_1]+ISNULL(' ('+[FIELDS_2]+')','')
                from(
                        select id, [FIELD_1],
                               stuff((
                                   select ',' + t3.[FIELD_2]
                                   from   @t3 t3 
                                   where  t3.[FIELD_1] = t1.[FIELD_1]
                                   for    xml path ('')
                               ),1,1, '') as [FIELDS_2]
                        from   @t1 t1
                         where  t1.[ID] = t2.[ID])t           for    xml path ('')
                               ),1,1, '') as [FIELDS]
from   @t2 t2
```